# Pythonic way to print data this data with headers

Tags: python

I have this dataset:

```
[('Stuff', '  ')
('Available in several colors.', '  ')
('A fits B by Sometimes.', '  ')
('handle      $148', 'A ')
('handle base  $23', 'A ')
('mirror base      $24', 'A ')
(' handle      $31', 'B ')
('handle base,     $23', 'B ')
('Mirror      $24', 'B ')
]
```

What I need to do is print this data with a "header" based off the second item in the list. Only printing the header when it changes. In this sample, the only 3 options are "  ", "A ", and "B ".  But in my actual data set there could be 100+ different options, so hard coding them in is not really an options.

I want the printed data to look like this (skipping the "  ")

```
Stuff.
Available in several colors.
A fits B by Sometimes.
A ----------------------
handle      $148
handle base  $23
mirror base      $24
B ----------------------
 handle      $31
handle base,     $23
Mirror      $24
```

the only way to do this I can think of is to hard code the values in, but with 100+ possibilities this would take forever. There must be a better way.

```
a_printed = False
b_printed = False
for item in list1:
    if item[1] == '  ':
        print(item[0])
    elif item[1] == 'A ':
        if a_printed != True:
            print('A --------------')
        a_printed = True
        print(item[0])
    elif item[1] == 'B ':
        if b_printed != True:
            print('B --------------')
        b_printed = True
        print(item[0])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank you for this response. I will look into this. It does look like with this I might have to groupby. It is important I keep these statements in this specific order, and I am not sure if the group by will change the order.

Comment: `itertools.groupby` will not change the order at all

Comment: Even without `groupby` you don't need to hard-code the headers. Just set a variable to the current header. Then in the loop, check if the new header is different from the variable. If it is, display the new header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to hard-code the header values, just set a variable to the header and test if the new header is different.

```
last_header = '  '
for value, header in list1:
    if header != last_header:
        print(header, '--------------')
        last_header = header
    print value
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Something simple that did the job.  IDK why but my brain just froze trying to figure this out. Thank you Thank you Thank you!